# What unlocks the three final Government Plaza buildings?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

The Civilopedia entries for the War Department, National History Museum, and Royal Society list only one of the previous buildings as being required, but I only just now am able to build them. I haven't been checking regularly, but I just recently entered the Atomic era by researching Rocketry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Tier 3 Government.

The plaza is linked to your advancement in the Civics tree, not the Science.